# How can I transfer a single table to another database in MSSQL server using VB.NET's SMO class?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, smo

I can already create a database but when I use the code below, it transfers all the tables without any records. Additionally how would I code that only a single specific table will be transferred?

```
Dim conn As New ServerConnection("NPSS-OJT", "sa", "rms")
        Dim srv As New Server(conn)
        Dim db As Database = srv.Databases("bos_primary_db")
        Dim dbCopy As Database = New Database(srv, Main.dbName)

        Dim xfr As Transfer
        xfr = New Transfer(db)
        xfr.CopyAllTables = True
        xfr.Options.WithDependencies = True
        xfr.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = True
        xfr.DestinationDatabase = dbCopy.Name
        xfr.DestinationServer = srv.Name
        xfr.DestinationLoginSecure = True
        xfr.CopySchema = True
        xfr.CopyData = True

        xfr.TransferData()
```

Updated Code:

```
Shared Sub transferTables()
        Dim conn As New ServerConnection("NPSS-OJT", "sa", "rms")
        Dim srv As New Server(conn)
        Dim db As Database = srv.Databases("bos_primary_db")
        Dim dbCopy As Database = New Database(srv, Main.dbName)

        Dim xfr As Transfer
        xfr = New Transfer(db)
        xfr.CopyAllTables = False
        xfr.Options.WithDependencies = False
        xfr.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = True
        xfr.DestinationDatabase = dbCopy.Name
        xfr.DestinationServer = srv.Name
        xfr.DestinationLoginSecure = True
        xfr.CopySchema = True
        xfr.CopyData = True
        xfr.Options.DriAll = False
        xfr.Options.DriDefaults = True
        xfr.Options.DriIndexes = True
        xfr.Options.DriPrimaryKey = True
        xfr.Options.DriUniqueKeys = True
        xfr.Options.DriForeignKeys = False
        xfr.ObjectList.Add("Accounting")
        xfr.TransferData()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set

```
xfr.CopyAllTables = False
xfr.Options.WithDependencies = False
```

also you should transfer keys

```
xfr.Options.DriAll = False 
xfr.Options.DriDefaults = True
xfr.Options.DriIndexes = True
xfr.Options.DriPrimaryKey = True
xfr.Options.DriUniqueKeys = True
xfr.Options.DriForeignKeys = False
```

and then

**EDIT** (I changed adding of the table in the list of transfered objects)

```
xfr.ObjectList.Add(db.Tables("table_name"))
xfr.TransferData()
```

To transfer specified object between databases you need to add this object to `ObjectList` but not just the object's name.

Comment: It's still transferring all the tables without any records. I also got an error afterwards.

Error: ERROR : errorCode=0 description=Transferring columns of data type "sql_variant" is not supported. helpFile= helpContext=0 idofInterfaceWithError={C81DFC5A-3B22-4DA3-BD3B-10BF861A7F9C}

Comment: Are you sure, that you set `CopyAllTables` and `Options.WithDependencies` to `False`? To eliminate the error you need to convert column with data type `sql_variant` to some another data type.

Comment: Yes they are both false already. How can I do what you said in the second sentence?

Comment: You need to analyze the values which are stored in this column and then change column data type in table design panel in, for examplte, SQL Server Managment Studio. I don't know how it is possible to convert column data type during data transfer by SMO.

Comment: It's stll transferring all the tables even if the 'CopyAllTables' and 'Options.WithDependencies' are set to False. Isn't there an easier way to transfer a single table using SMO?

Comment: No. It is the easiest way. With `xfr.ObjectList.Add("object_name")
xfr.TransferData()` you can transfer any specified object: table, stored procedure, server role etc. Please, post last version of your VB code.

Comment: There I have update my post to include the last version of my VB code.

Comment: My bad, it seems it is transferring records it just occurs too slow. The only problem is that it copies all the tables not just the one I have included in ObjectList.Add and the sql_variant still has the same error.

Comment: Why is my new code not working? It's getting an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


`Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("C:\Users\Nexus\Desktop\tables.txt")
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            xfr.ObjectList.Add(db.Tables(sr.ReadLine))
        Loop
        xfr.TransferData()`

Comment: `ReadLine` is a method. So you nee to set brackets after it call:  `xfr.ObjectList.Add(db.Tables(sr.ReadLine()))`